# How to write a common url routing rule to nearest parent location for ui-router

Tags: angularjs, redirect, routes, angular-ui-router, rule

I'm using `ui-router` for an Angular (1.4) WebApp. Everything is fine, but the URL redirect rules. I know I can define a set of redirect rules when an URL is unknown. But I'd like to make it more advanced. I want to redirect the request to its nearest parent location.

Here is a simplified case:

```
/                       // --> index.html
/apps/app/:id           // --> app.html
/apps/app/:id/status    // --> app.status.html
/unknown/path           // --> no path segment is registered at all, so redirect to index.html

MY WISH:
/apps/app/:id/unknown   // --> app.html (not redirect to index.html)
```

Here is corresponding code:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'index.html'
    }).
    .state('app', {
      url: '/apps/app/:id',
      templateUrl: 'app.html'
    })
    .state('app.status', {
      url: '/apps/app/:id/status',
      templateUrl: 'app.status.html'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

}])
```

In the real project, there are more than 20 state rules. But redirect to index.html is not user friendly. I'm looking for a smart way to redirect page to nearest page.

### Solution

Now I've got a solution. Note that `_.initial` comes from underscorejs.

```
$urlRouterProvider
  .otherwise(function($injector, $location) {
    var parentUrl = _.initial($location.path().split('/')).join('/');
    $location.path(parentUrl);
  });
```

Comment: Can you post your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle more complex redirects by:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
    // handle each case here
});
```

[ui-router otherwise](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#otherwise-for-invalid-routes)